# overwrite backbone History start method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, extend, browser-history, referenceerror

Based on a working web application with (Backbone.js 1.0.0), I need to overwrite history start method, to force polling to detect hash changes, and discard other options. On a new file I do this:

```
   var myHistory = Backbone.History.extend({
         start: function (options) {
            if (History.started) throw new Error("Backbone.history has already been started");
            History.started = true;
          // code here
         }
   }); 
   Backbone.history = new myHistory;
```

As result, I get an Error: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: History.

any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to refer to `Backbone.history` in your code or the current object, `this`?

Comment: thanks @Mark , I refer to `Backbone.history`. After import backbone.js, i'm importing that file. I do not think there is any mistake related to scope.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is fairly old, and you've probably solved it by now, but I recently had to do a similar thing. For me I replaced where it said 'History.started' with 'Backbone.History.started', as History.started is a variable in the original Backbone library.